# Objectify: delete entire row by id

Tags: android, google-app-engine, delete-row, objectify, objectify-delete

I need to check if a field contains specific `String`, and if it does - delete the entire row by id.
This code doesn't working:

```
Query<Bet> query = ofy().load().type(Movie.class);

        for (Movie m : query) {
            List<String> list = m.getActors();
            String search = "Brad Pitt";
            for (String str : list) {
                if (str.trim().contains(search)) {
                    ofy().delete().type(Movie.class).id(m.getId()).now();

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: When you say doesn't work.... do you get an error? you need to explicitly explain what you mean by "doesn't work".

Comment: Just took a look at your profile. You have 7 questions for none of which you accepted an answer. If you value the help of others you should upvote helpful answers and accept solutions. Otherwise people might become less willing to help you in the future.

Comment: @konqi thank you again for your patience and help. I will accept the answers, sorry for not doing it earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case (deleting all movies with Brad Pitt in it as an actor) you could delete the entity like this:

```
Query<Movie> query = ofy().load().type(User.class);

for (Movie m : query) {
    List<String> list = m.getActors();
    String search = "Brad Pitt";
    for (String str : list) {
        if (str.trim().contains(search)) {
            ofy().delete().entity(m).now();
        }
    }
}
```

Not that i delete with `delete().entity(...)`. Another option would be to delete by key like so `delete().key(Key.create(Movie.class, idToRemove)`. The former does something quite similar but since you have the whole entity you don't need to complicate things. Also if you delete with `entity(...)` it will work when the entity has a `@Parent` whereas if you delete by key you'd have to additionally specify the ancestor in `Key.create(ancestorKey, Movie.class, idToRemove)`.

I usually do multiple deletes like this:

```
Query<Movie> query = ofy().load().type(User.class);
List<Movie> toDelete = new ArrayList<>();

for (Movie m : query) {
    List<String> list = m.getActors();
    String search = "Brad Pitt";
    for (String str : list) {
        if (str.trim().contains(search)) {
            toDelete.add(m);
        }
    }
}

ofy().delete().entities(toDelete).now();
```

Performing database operations in a loop is bad style and should be avoided if possible.

**One more thing:**

If you must delete an entity by id the line would look like this:

```
ofy().delete().type(Movie.class).id(idToDelete);
```

However, as i hinted at before, if your `Movie` class has a parent this will not work because you must always specify the whole key, thus with ancestor the line would look like this:

```
Key<MyParentClass> parent = Key.create(MyParentClass.class, myParentId);
ofy().delete().type(Movie.class).parent(parent).id(idToDelete);
```

which is equivalent to

```
ofy().delete().key(Key.create(Key.create(MyParentClass.class, myParentId), Movie.class, idToDelete));
```

Comment: Thnx again! Unfortunately it didn't work, i've got an error:  `99% Endpoints configuration not updated.  The app returned an error when the Google Cloud Endpoints server attempted to communicate with it.
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload checkEndpointsServingStatusResult
99% See the deployment troubleshooting documentation for more information: https://developers.
99% Ignoring Endpoints failure and proceeding with update.
SEVERE: Endpoints configuration not updated.  The app returned an error when the Google Cloud Endpoints server attempted to communicate with it.

Comment: @GidiSprintzin That looks like a different issue entirely. Please open a new question with a MCV example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can analyze it. As a starting point i would clean the project and do a full rebuild.

Comment: I think the problem with my code is, that in the field i have an array that looks like that: `[{"stringValue":"yyy","indexed":false},{"stringValue":"Brad Pitt","indexed":false},{"stringValue":"jhon13","indexed":false}]` , and i don't know how to pull the name out.